# transform dict with nested array values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have the example data below, which is a default dictionary. I’m trying to transform it in to a dictionary like the desired output below, but I’m having trouble getting the keys to match the keys from the original dictionary.  I can get the values using the code below. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
res[0].item()
```

Output:

```
-1.613331913948059
```

Example data:

```
res

defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {0: array([-1.6133319], dtype=float32),
             1: array([-1.278326], dtype=float32),
             2: array([-0.68584293], dtype=float32),
             3: array([-1.2741858], dtype=float32),
             4: array([-0.81194735], dtype=float32)})
```

Desired output:

```
{0: -1.6133319,
 1: -1.278326,
 2: -0.68584293,
 3: -1.2741858,
 4: -0.81194735}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, This dictionary comprehension should do the trick :

```
{k:v[0] for k,v in res.items()}

{0: -1.6133319, 1: -1.278326, 2: -0.68584293, 3: -1.2741858, 4: -0.81194735}
```

Comment: thanks for getting back to me so quickly, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
{k: res[k].item() for k in res}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have done the trick

```
test_res={}

for ids in list(res.keys()):
  test_res[ids]=res[ids].item()
```

Comment: Even though this works, it will be slower than a dict comprehension